# Start an Intent from onTouch

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, ontouch

I tried starting a new activity from onTouch block but the application terminates suddenly. My code is:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    ....
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,SecondOne.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
    break;
    .....
    return true;
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: Can you display your log when it crashes?

Comment: Please post your logcat or the error that you are receiving.

Comment: 'terminates suddenly' is way too vague to conclusively diagnose a problem. Please post a logcat, a stacktrace, anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my initial guess without seeing a log is that something is either Null or the second activity is not declared in your manifest.

also i would say:

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstOne.this,SecondOne.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    break;
```

Comment: thanx very much. there was a line of code throwing nullpointer exc. now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the actual context in the intent.

`Intent myIntent = new Intent(ThisClass.this, SecondOne.class);`

With `thisClass` being whatever class you are writing this code in.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be having problems.

1. You can not use `break;` outside a loop. So first thing, make sure you eliminate that from your `onTouch()` function.
2. Make sure you have this in your AndroidManifest file.

   `<activity android:name=".SecondOne" >
   </activity>`
3. Make sure that your `context` variable is valid. i.e if your first activity name is `First`, its valid `context` should be equal to  `First.this`

I am assuming you implementation of OnTouchListener is ok.

Your `OnTouchListener` implementation

```
private final class OT implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        context = First.this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondOne.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Binding to your button to start another activity.

```
yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new OT());
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SecondOne" > 
</activity>
```